# What's the CSS to uncheck a checkbox which you increase the screen width?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Currently clicking the ☰ label toggles the mobile menu in mobile width.

Increasing screen width hides mobile menu.

PROBLEM: If left checked, the toggled menu is still checked when resized to mobile width.

NEED: Checkbox to uncheck when the screen width exceeds X pixels.

Code so far:

```css
#toggle {
  display: none;
  /*hide checkbox*/
}

#toggle:checked+.togglemenu {
  /*show menu on click*/
  display: block;
}

.togglemenu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/*hide menu width increase*/

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--toggle-->
<li>
  <a class="menu" href="#">
    <label for="toggle">☰</label>
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="togglemenu">test</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

I'm sure I've done it before, just forgotten over time.
Any ideas? Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is not doable in CSS. You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have any HTML + CSS to show us?  This is unguessable without some details.  But as Jon said, if you are actually unchecking a checkbox control you will need JS.

Comment: added code for you

Comment: @JonUleis That's not true at all. You can easily hide the element with a breakpoint in CSS.

Comment: @meagar OP is already doing that - did you miss their code? The part that's not doable is altering a checkbox to be unchecked based on a media query.

Comment: @JonUleis Sorry, I did indeed completely misinterpret the question, and your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You will need JavaScript to do this.

You can listen for window resize, and then uncheck the checkbox when your desired size has been reached.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 480px)').matches) {
        document.getElementById('toggle').checked = false;
    }
}, true);
```